# Beego skipping some migrations

Tags: go, beego, golang-migrate

When running beego migration, it shows that all migrations are executed, but it skips some migrations. Please find the scenario.

- I have created a migration and executed it today.
- I am merging another branch which has a migration created yesterday.
- When I am running bee migration again, it is not executing the one which was created yesterday, but it will execute newly added migration after the last executed one.

```
Beego     : 1.10.1  
GoVersion : go1.10.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Beego Migration only checking files after last migration. This is a Bug.

An issue has been created for this
https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/3657

**Update**

This issue has been fixed https://github.com/astaxie/beego/pull/3658